# Elements of $L^p$ and nice representatives of equivalence classes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

Considering $L^p$ $( 1 \leq  p < \infty)$ as a normed vector space, each element of $L^p$ is actually an Equivalent class. Take $[f] \in L^p $ as an Equivalent class, What is the **Nicest** possible function $g$ such that $g \in [f]$ (i.e. $g=f$ almost everywhere).

By the word **Nice** you are free to consider any good topological or algebraic property like continuity, differentiability, boundedness, etc... (as many as you can)

Second question: Let $N$ denotes the set of such **Nice** Properties, imposing $N$ as set of conditions on $g$, can one identify $g$ uniquely ? In other words can we rewrite  $L^p$ in following way

$$L^p = \{ g : R\rightarrow R \cup \{\pm \infty\}  \quad  | \quad  \|g\|_p < \infty  ,~g\text{ satisfies }N    \}$$

This makes we can think about  $L^p$ as a set of nice functions, free of any confusing equivalent classes.

Clarification: My intention is to find a set of finite conditions called $N$ , when we imposing them, $g$ is determined uniquely, in order to replace this $g$ by $[f]$ to rewrite $L^p$ as above. 
Lusin's theorem says one can pick $g \in [f]$ such that $g$ is continuous except on very small set (as small as you want but might have positive measure).This might be helpful but still can't give us the set of condition $N$ !

Comment: Lifting theory is well developed. Start with $$ $$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_theory

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure using that, I can identify $N$.

Answer (score 2):

In harmonic analysis one frequently defines a modification of $f$ by taking the new value $f(x)$ as the limiti of averages of $f$ over balls centered at $x$, with radius tending to 0. You do this at every point for which the limit exists. If $f$ is equivalent to a continuous function, this method produces the continuous representative. By Lebesgue differentiation this limit exists at almost every $x$ and coincides with the original value of $f(x)$ for any locally $L^1$ function; of course it remains the question of how to redefine $f$ at points where the limit do not exist; maybe one can set $f=0$ there. I guess you can not do better than this, but I might be wrong since I do not know lifting theory.

Comment: what is  significant about this limit when $f$ is not continuous ? Actually when $f$ is equivalent to continuous function? if we now $f$ is equivalent to a continuous  then we are done with $[f]$. no need think about that procedure .

Comment: Is it better than Lusin's Theorem?   
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I would take lower or upper limit for any point (depending on what we need).

Comment: @FedorPetrov Takin lower/upper limit of what ? what limit?  can clarify it?

Comment: Of averages over small balls.

Comment: Yes this is the most elegant solution

Comment: @nonlinear: Lusin does not give you a function $f$. This method gives you a 'nicest' element in the class of $f$. Maybe you should clarify your thoughts by thinking what you would like for a function of one variable with a finite number of jumps

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona can you put here a link showing explicit definition of that modification ? like a wikipedia page

Comment: $F(x)=\limsup_{r\to0}|B_r(x)|^{-1}\int_{B_r(x)}f(y)dy$